# How to wrap command arguments with /bin/sh -c and execvpe()

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

Currently I'm trying to write a program that takes in a custom command and arguments from the user and execute it.

I'm trying to use execvpe that can pass in command args and env together.

However, I'm not able to figure out what's the right way to call execvpe in my case.

For example this command input: ps aux

I don't want to build up a command string as then I need to be careful about escaping quotes and semicolons (ie: JSON strings), and ideally just pass that as one arg in the array.

I see that the only way I can run this directly in bash is like this:

```
/bin/sh -c "ps \$0" aux
```

However, trying to translate that into execvpe I tried this:

```
char * argv[] = { "sh", "-c", "\"ps \\$0\"", "aux", NULL };
execve("/bin/sh", (char **)argv, NULL);
```

However this gives me a error:

```
aux: ps $0: command not found
```

What's the correct way to formulate this with execvpe?

Answer (score 0):

What you did in your C code is equivalent to:

```
$ bash -c '"ps \$0"' aux
aux: ps $0: command not found
```

You can't backslash the double quotes and dollar sign. Try this: `{ "sh", "-c", "ps $0", "aux", NULL }`

P.S. I can smell that what you are trying to do is very vulnerable.

Comment: PPS. `strace` is very handy debugging execve problems.

Comment: I actually tried without the slash and it didn't work too. It's somewhat vulnerable yes but we do have extra security around these.